# Nutch Newbie - JSP with html problem

Tags: java, jsp, web, lucene, nutch

System: Mac OSX

I have set up nutch so that it crawls and indexes my site. It also returns search results. My problem is that I want to customise the Nutch index.jsp and search.jsp pages to fit with my site. Ive read up and on jsp and it says its just a matter of putting in the html tags and then using <% %> to enclose the Java scriplets you want. For some reason nothing changes when i edit the files (index and search)

Here is what the original file displays:

```
<%@ page
  session="false"
  import="java.io.*"
  import="java.util.*"
%><%
  String language =
    ResourceBundle.getBundle("org.nutch.jsp.search", request.getLocale())
    .getLocale().getLanguage();
  String requestURI = HttpUtils.getRequestURL(request).toString();
  String base = requestURI.substring(0, requestURI.lastIndexOf('/'));
  response.sendRedirect(language + "/");
%>
```

Here is my edited version with sum gibberish test added to test it:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

gigigyigig


<%@ page
  session="false"
  import="java.io.*"
  import="java.util.*"
%><%
  String language =
    ResourceBundle.getBundle("org.nutch.jsp.search", request.getLocale())
    .getLocale().getLanguage();
  String requestURI = HttpUtils.getRequestURL(request).toString();
  String base = requestURI.substring(0, requestURI.lastIndexOf('/'));
  response.sendRedirect(language + "/");
%>

ghjgjkbkhb
hjgjvjhvj

</body>
</html>
```

Nothing has changed tho and the nutch homepage/index.jsp still displays the same as original. This is my first encounter with JSP so its just what ive picked up so far. Can anyone tell me why the page isnt displaying the html with gibberish typed??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have my search totaly modified.  However I  have my `<html>...` tags after the second scriptlet ie `<% %>` not `<%@ page`.
As for your index.jsp modified it has a redirection `response.sendRedirect` and therefore it looks normal to me that you see nothing.
Also I presume you took care of loading the jsp pages at the right place under the tomcat/webapps tree, because the standard ant make file doesn't. So I ended up adding some Ant task to patch my test website.
Beware if you are going to change the .jar files you also need to restart Tomcat.

Comment: I put all the <html> tags after the 2nd scriptlet as instructed. The files are in the tomcat/webapps/nutch directory but the page is loaded from localhost:8080/nutch so i think everything is okay there. 
There is still no change in the page tho, gibberish not showing yet. I am not sure what the response.sendRedirect does which u spoke of so i might have to look into that some more. But still no change in the page.

Comment: response.sendRedirect does pretty much the same thing as location.replace in javaScript however on the server side. It should put you on page `localhost:8080/nutch/en/` if u use english, which actually is nutch/en/search.html. Search.jsp gets only called after submitting a first query.